# The NLP Tagger called SENNA

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, senna

I have a question about the nlp tagger called SENNA, that is developed by Collbert and his colleagues based on their paper: Natural Language Processing (almost) from Scratch.

Does SENNA (it's code which available at this address: http://ronan.collobert.com/senna/download.html) contain any code for training the neural network?

Or it just uses information that is obtained by training the network (it is trained beforehand and its code is not in SENNA)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SENNA contains code for training neural network. Take a look at SENNA_nn.h & SENNA_nn.c for reference, it shows the implementation of different layers mentioned in the paper.

[image]

Comment: These functions are useful in the prediction phase but the code misses the functions that are used for learning (updating the weights of the model).

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think so. The functions @illuminatus refers to are there because they are needed at inference time. AFAIK, you have to write the learning functions by yourself.